# IPhone Architecture

Tags: iphone, ios, architecture

Can someone explain IPhone architecture in detail.

What happens when we click on a button, how hardware responds to that event.

Thanks
Jithendra

Comment: http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/iphone1.htm

Comment: I know i will get down votes to this question. But no alternative

Comment: Stackoverflow never provide complete solution, use google first for what you are looking for and if you stuck somewhere then post question in SO with proper quality inputs

Comment: I alreay did google. I didnt find detailed info..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [How the iPhone Works](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/iphone.htm), especially how [the touch works part](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/iphone1.htm). It has detailed information on how everything is handled including the touch/multiple touch etc. Cannot add all the information here, so posting as a link alone.

Comment: This got good info about IPhone.